# MySQL select row dependent on if a specific value exists for a specific column

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a very specific problem and I've been battling with for a while now trying to solve it with no luck.

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is to get the lowest price from a pricing table 'product_line_price' based on a currency value. The trick is that the product_line_price table does not always contain a value for a specific currency, in which case it must default to selecting the default 'AUD' currency. This table also contains multiple records per product, with different pricing schemes, but I am only interested in the cheapest (min price) of them all, for the specific currency I am querying.

The end goal is used for a 'faceted search' on products, where a user can select a price ranged to list products within that specific range.

This is the overall query that I've tried which I thought was the closest attempt:

```
SELECT    * 
FROM      product_line 
LEFT JOIN 
          ( 
                   SELECT   idproduct_line, 
                            idprice_group, 
                            CASE 
                                     WHEN EXISTS 
                                              ( 
                                                     SELECT currency_code 
                                                     FROM   product_line_price 
                                                     WHERE  currency_code = 'GBP' 
                                                     AND    idproduct_line = product_line_price.idproduct_line) THEN Min(price)
                                     ELSE Min(price)*0.5098 
                            END AS userprice 
                   FROM     product_line_price 
                   WHERE    !deleted 
                   AND 
                            CASE 
                                     WHEN EXISTS 
                                              ( 
                                                     SELECT currency_code 
                                                     FROM   product_line_price 
                                                     WHERE  currency_code = 'GBP' 
                                                     AND    idproduct_line = product_line_price.idproduct_line) THEN currency_code = 'GBP'
                                     ELSE currency_code = 'AUD' 
                            END 
                   GROUP BY idproduct_line 
                   ORDER BY product_line_price.idproduct_line ASC) AS product_line_price 
ON        product_line.idproduct_line = product_line_price.idproduct_line 
WHERE     !product_line.deleted 
AND       product_line.idproduct_line_status = 1 
AND       product_line.idproduct_line IN 
          ( 
                 SELECT `idproduct_line` 
                 from   `product_line_has_product_category` 
                 where  `idproduct_category` = '103') 
AND       (( 
                              product_line_price.idprice_group IN 
                              ( 
                                     SELECT `idprice_group` 
                                     FROM   `price_group` 
                                     WHERE  !`deleted` 
                                     AND    `PUBLIC` 
                                     AND    `active`)) 
          AND       ( 
                              userprice <= 250)) 
ORDER BY  product_line.idproduct_line ASC
```

And the sub query I'm having trouble with is this one:

```
SELECT   idproduct_line, 
                            idprice_group, 
                            CASE 
                                     WHEN EXISTS 
                                              ( 
                                                     SELECT currency_code 
                                                     FROM   product_line_price 
                                                     WHERE  currency_code = 'GBP' 
                                                     AND    idproduct_line = product_line_price.idproduct_line) THEN Min(price)
                                     ELSE Min(price)*0.5098 
                            END AS userprice 
                   FROM     product_line_price 
                   WHERE    !deleted 
                   AND 
                            CASE 
                                     WHEN EXISTS 
                                              ( 
                                                     SELECT currency_code 
                                                     FROM   product_line_price 
                                                     WHERE  currency_code = 'GBP' 
                                                     AND    idproduct_line = product_line_price.idproduct_line) THEN currency_code = 'GBP'
                                     ELSE currency_code = 'AUD' 
                            END 
                   GROUP BY idproduct_line 
                   ORDER BY product_line_price.idproduct_line ASC
```

So, I need to be able to retrieve the value for the GBP currency if it exists, otherwise default to the AUD currency (and apply a currency conversion). Some of the numbers here are hard-coded for testing, and will be supplied via variables later.

I have a feeling that with the above subquery, the EXISTS subqueries are not correctly using the idproduct_line values, as when I run it, I ONLY get GBP results, even though there are plenty of records in that table with no GBP result. The subquery I'm talking about is this one:

```
SELECT currency_code 
FROM   product_line_price 
WHERE  currency_code = 'GBP' 
AND    idproduct_line = product_line_price.idproduct_line
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? I feel like I am so close, but something in that subquery is just wrong, and SQL is not my strongest suit.

## EDIT 1:

My main concern is with the sub query that contains the EXISTS clauses, I know the rest of it works and provided the entire query purely for contextual purposes.

You can download a dump of the table in question and some sample data from the following link. The sample data contains pricing for 3 products, one with only AUD pricing, one with AUD and GBP pricing, and one with pricing for multiple currencies.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h1i23f5ac2jmrvn/product_line_price.sql?dl=0

The query I am running against this data is:

```
SELECT   idproduct_line, 
                            idprice_group,
                            currency_code, 
                            CASE 
                                     WHEN EXISTS 
                                              ( 
                                                     SELECT currency_code 
                                                     FROM   product_line_price_2 
                                                     WHERE  currency_code = 'GBP' 
                                                     AND    idproduct_line = product_line_price_2.idproduct_line AND !deleted) THEN Min(price)
                                     ELSE Min(price)*0.5098 
                            END AS userprice 
                   FROM     product_line_price_2 
                   WHERE    !deleted 
                   AND 
                            CASE 
                                     WHEN EXISTS 
                                              ( 
                                                     SELECT currency_code 
                                                     FROM   product_line_price_2 
                                                     WHERE  currency_code = 'GBP' 
                                                     AND    idproduct_line = product_line_price_2.idproduct_line AND !deleted) THEN currency_code = 'GBP'
                                     ELSE currency_code = 'AUD' 
                            END 
                   GROUP BY idproduct_line 
                   ORDER BY product_line_price_2.idproduct_line ASC
```

My expected output is 3 records, 2 with GBP pricing displaying the minimum value, and one with AUD pricing displaying the minimum value, converted to GBP (via the '*0.5098' in the query).

The actual output I am seeing is only 2 records with GBP pricing, so it is ignoring the AUD pricing.

Answer (score 0):

Tried my best to understand and use your existing code, you can try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    product_line 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            idproduct_line, 
            idprice_group, 
            CASE 
                WHEN EXISTS (
                    SELECT
                        currency_code 
                    FROM
                        product_line_price 
                    WHERE
                        currency_code = 'GBP' 
                        AND idproduct_line = product_line_price.idproduct_line
                ) THEN
                    MIN(price)
                ELSE
                    MIN(price) * 0.5098 
            END AS userprice
        FROM
            product_line_price 
        WHERE
            deleted = 0
            AND CASE WHEN EXISTS (
                SELECT
                    currency_code 
                FROM
                    product_line_price 
                WHERE
                    currency_code = 'GBP' 
                    AND idproduct_line = product_line_price.idproduct_line
            ) THEN
                currency_code = 'GBP'
                ELSE
                    currency_code = 'AUD' 
            END 
        GROUP BY
            idproduct_line 
        ORDER BY
            idproduct_line ASC
    ) AS product_line_price ON product_line.idproduct_line = product_line_price.idproduct_line 
WHERE
    product_line.deleted = 0
    AND product_line.idproduct_line_status = 1 
    AND product_line.idproduct_line IN (
        SELECT
            idproduct_line
        FROM
            product_line_has_product_category
        WHERE
            idproduct_category = '103'
    )
    AND product_line_price.idprice_group IN ( 
        SELECT idprice_group
        FROM price_group
        WHERE
            !deleted
            AND PUBLIC
            AND active
            AND userprice <= 250
    )
ORDER BY
    product_line.idproduct_line ASC;
```

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
    pl.*,
    IF(plp.currency_code = 'GBP', MIN(IFNULL(plp.price, 0)), MIN(IFNULL(plp.price, 0)) * 0.5098)
FROM
    product_line pl
    LEFT JOIN product_line_price plp ON plp.idproduct_line = pl.idproduct_line
WHERE
    !pl.deleted
    AND !plp.deleted
    AND plp.currency_code IN ('GBP','AUD')
    AND pl.idproduct_line_status = 1 
    AND pl.idproduct_line IN (
        SELECT
            idproduct_line
        FROM
            product_line_has_product_category
        WHERE
            idproduct_category = '103'
    )
    AND plp.idprice_group IN ( 
        SELECT idprice_group
        FROM price_group
        WHERE
            !deleted
            AND public = 1
            AND active
            AND userprice <= 250
    )
ORDER BY
    pl.idproduct_line ASC;
```

Lastly, please try this:

```
SELECT 
    pl.*,
    plp.idproduct_line,
    plp.idprice_group
    IF(plp.currency_code = 'GBP', MIN(IFNULL(plp.price, 0)), MIN(IFNULL(plp.price, 0)) * 0.5098)
FROM
    product_line pl
    LEFT JOIN product_line_price plp ON plp.idproduct_line = pl.idproduct_line
    LEFT JOIN product_line_has_product_category plhpc ON plhpc.idproduct_line = pl.idproduct_line
    LEFT JOIN price_group pg ON pg.idprice_group = plp.idprice_group
WHERE
    pl.deleted = 0
    AND pl.idproduct_line_status = 1
    AND plp.deleted = 0
    AND plp.currency_code IN ('GBP','AUD')
    AND plhpc.idproduct_category = '103'
    AND !pg.deleted
    AND pg.public
    AND pg.active
    AND pg.userprice <= 250
ORDER BY
    pl.idproduct_line ASC;
```

Comment: I tried running just the sub query and its yielding the same results as mine, I feel as though the issue may be with the GROUP BY or that the sub query within for EXISTS is not applying on a 'per row' basis.

Comment: If I edit the subquery to GROUP BY the idproduct_line and the currency_code, then I get the expected results, although I end up with duplicate products, which makes me think that perhaps the WHERE idproduct_line = product_line_price.idproduct_line is not working as it should within the EXISTS subquery.. I expect it to lookup for the current record of the parent query, search for a price record that contains that ID and has a price of GBP and if its not found, then use the AUD price.

Comment: maybe can post the sample from the source tables and your expected result set output mate

Comment: I've updated the question with a dump of the table and some sample data, with the query im running against it, and my expected results vs results I am getting

Comment: need to know if there is any foreign key to help like into the following tables from the existing tables. tables: product_line_has_product_category, product_line_has_product_category

Answer (score 0):

So after a long struggle and some help from a work colleague we took a different approach and found the solution to this issue.

```
SELECT product_line.idproduct_line, 
       Min(local_price.price)    local_userprice, 
       Min(fallback_price.price) fallback_userprice 
FROM   product_line 
       INNER JOIN product_line_has_product_category 
               ON product_line.idproduct_line = 
                  product_line_has_product_category.idproduct_line 
                  AND 103 = product_line_has_product_category.idproduct_category 
       LEFT JOIN (product_line_price local_price 
                  INNER JOIN price_group local_price_group 
                          ON local_price.idprice_group = 
                             local_price_group.idprice_group 
                             AND ! local_price_group.deleted 
                             AND local_price_group.PUBLIC 
                             AND local_price_group.active) 
              ON product_line.idproduct_line = local_price.idproduct_line 
                 AND 'GBP' = local_price.currency_code 
       LEFT JOIN (product_line_price fallback_price 
                  INNER JOIN price_group fallback_price_group 
                          ON fallback_price.idprice_group = 
                             fallback_price_group.idprice_group 
                             AND ! fallback_price_group.deleted 
                             AND fallback_price_group.PUBLIC 
                             AND fallback_price_group.active) 
              ON product_line.idproduct_line = fallback_price.idproduct_line 
                 AND 'AUD' = fallback_price.currency_code 
WHERE ! product_line.deleted 
      AND product_line.idproduct_line_status = 1 
GROUP  BY product_line.idproduct_line 
HAVING ( local_userprice IS NULL 
         AND fallback_userprice <= 250 ) 
        OR ( local_userprice <= 250 ) 
ORDER  BY product_line.idproduct_line ASC
```

Using joins, cross-referenced the values for GBP and AUD (this gave is 2 columns for both price and currency in the same row) .. then we can compare each column using a HAVING clause and the results are success!